# google maps api : determine if point is inside shape

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have created a rectangle on the map along with a listener for `bounds_changed`. It calls a method to determine if a point is within the adjusted rectangle. However I'm getting the error `Cannot read property 'getLength' of undefined` when I change the size of the rectangle. This error is coming from the call to `containsLocation`.

In my init:

```
rectangle = new google.maps.Rectangle({
                bounds: bounds,
                editable: true,
                draggable: true,
                geodesic: true,
                map: map
            });


google.maps.event.addListener(rectangle , 'bounds_changed', isWithinPoly);
```

function to determine if point falls in adjusted rectangle:

```
function isWithinPoly(){
    console.log(rectangle);
    var point = new google.maps.LatLng(51.331, 3.538);
    var isWithinPolygon = google.maps.geometry.poly.containsLocation(point, rectangle);
    console.log(isWithinPolygon);

}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`containsLocation` expects a polygon as argument, not a rectangle.

For a rectangle use the method `contains` of the bounds:

```
var isWithinRectangle = rectangle.getBounds().contains(point);
```

Comment: Thanks! This did it, do you have a link to where that is in the API docs? I can't find it.

Comment: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference?hl=en&csw=1#LatLngBounds